# Was the birth of Lava and Kusha the result of normal human conjugal union?

Tags: rama, sita, kusha, lava

A lot of births in Hindu scripture do not involve a man and a woman ("Sita" means furrow - Sita was found by Janaka in a furrow).

Rama is a human avatara of Vishnu - are Lava and Kusha said to have resulted from a normal human union?

Comment: It might be implied that they were, but scripture is not explicit either way.